# There is two triangles with common edge in graph $\Gamma$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, pigeonhole-principle, extremal-graph-theory

> Let $\Gamma$ be a graph with $2n$ vertices and $n^2+1$ edges. Than there is two subgraphs $K', K'' \subset \Gamma$ both isomorphic to $K_3$ such that they have a common edge.

I have tried to count subgraphs isomorphic to $K_3$ using same methods as when we are proving Turan's theorem and than apply pigeonhole principle but i'am stuck...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generalize the statement to apply to graphs with an odd number of vertices, rather than requiring $|V|=2n$, and then induct on $|V|$.

By Mantel's theorem, if the graph has at least $\frac{|V|^2}{4}+1$ edges, then it contains a triangle subgraph $K'$. If there is another triangle $K''$ sharing an edge with $K'$, then we are done. If not, then you can show that deleting the vertices of $K'$ creates a graph with $|V|-3$ vertices and at least $\frac{(|V|-3)^2}{4}+1$ edges, provided $|V| \ge 5$, and you can find what you want in the remainder by the inductive hypothesis.